# Guava Resources.readLines() for Zip/Gzip files

Tags: java, url, guava, readline

I've found the Resources.readLines() and Files.readLines() to be helpfull in simplifiying my code.
The problem is that I often read gzip-compressed txt-files or txt-files in zip archives from URL's (HTTP and FTP).
Is there a way to use Guava's methods to read from these URL's too? Or is that only possible with Java's GZIPInputStream/ZipInputStream?

Comment: If you're on Java 8 then you can use `BufferedReader#lines()`.

Comment: Ping! I've added a `ByteSource` for Zip in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own `ByteSource`s:

For GZip:

```
public class GzippedByteSource extends ByteSource {
  private final ByteSource source;
  public GzippedByteSource(ByteSource gzippedSource) { source = gzippedSource; }
  @Override public InputStream openStream() throws IOException {
    return new GZIPInputStream(source.openStream());
  }
}
```

Then use it:

```
Charset charset = ... ;
new GzippedByteSource(Resources.asByteSource(url)).toCharSource(charset).readLines();
```

Here is the implementation for the Zip. This assumes that you read only one entry.

```
public static class ZipEntryByteSource extends ByteSource {
  private final ByteSource source;
  private final String entryName;
  public ZipEntryByteSource(ByteSource zipSource, String entryName) {
    this.source = zipSource;
    this.entryName = entryName;
  }
  @Override public InputStream openStream() throws IOException {
    final ZipInputStream in = new ZipInputStream(source.openStream());
    while (true) {
      final ZipEntry entry = in.getNextEntry();
      if (entry == null) {
        in.close();
        throw new IOException("No entry named " + entry);
      } else if (entry.getName().equals(this.entryName)) {
        return new InputStream() {
          @Override
          public int read() throws IOException {
            return in.read();
          }

          @Override
          public void close() throws IOException {
            in.closeEntry();
            in.close();
          }
        };
      } else {
        in.closeEntry();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
Charset charset = ... ;
String entryName = ... ; // Name of the entry inside the zip file.
new ZipEntryByteSource(Resources.asByteSource(url), entryName).toCharSource(charset).readLines();
```

Comment: `GzipInputStream` should be `GZIPInputStream`

Answer (score 1):

As Olivier Grégoire said, you can create the necessary `ByteSource`s for whatever compression scheme you need in order to use Guava's `readLines` function.

For zip archives though, although it's possible to do it, I don't think it's worth it.  It will be easier to make your own `readLines` method that iterates over the zip entries and reads the lines of each entry on your own.  Here's a class that demonstrates how to read and output the lines of a URL pointing at a zip archive:

```
public class ReadLinesOfZippedUrl {
    public static List<String> readLines(String urlStr, Charset charset) {
        List<String> retVal = new LinkedList<>();
        try (ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new URL(urlStr).openStream())) {
            for (ZipEntry zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry(); zipEntry != null; zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) {
                // don't close this reader or you'll close the underlying zip stream
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zipInputStream, charset));
                retVal.addAll(reader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList())); // slurp all the lines from one entry
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String urlStr = "http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0-sources.jar";
        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        List<String> lines = readLines(urlStr, charset);
        lines.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```